# How can I load a NeoVim plugin with Packer conditionally from local or remote?

Tags: lua, neovim, neovim-plugin

I am developing an experimental NeoVim plugin https://github.com/KaiWalter/azure-functions.nvim and want to load the local source code on the development system and load it remotely from repository on other machines.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use VIM API `vim.fn.isdirectory` to check whether the local directory is present.

```
...
return require('packer').startup(function(use)
  use 'wbthomason/packer.nvim'

  -- My plugins here
...
  local user = os.getenv("USERNAME")
  local path = "/home/" .. user .. "/src/azure-functions.nvim"
  if vim.fn.isdirectory(path) ~= 0 then
    use {
      path,
      config = function()
        require("azure-functions").setup({})
      end,
    }
  else
    use {
      "kaiwalter/azure-functions.nvim",
      config = function()
        require("azure-functions").setup({})
      end,
    }
  end
...
end)
```

I was not able to achieve this with `cond` condition like

```
  use {
    path,
    opt = true,
    cond = function()
      return vim.fn.isdirectory(path) ~= 0,
    end,
    config = function()
      require("azure-functions").setup({})
    end,
  }
```

as the `cond` specification does not seem influence whether a package is installed or not.